# Three.js - Planes overflow opacity

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl, mesh

I'm trying put two planes on the same (or nearest possible) position.

When two planes of different materials and color are in the same position, depending on camera position and view angle, the opacity of the front plane is not full, and lets you see the back plane, at least partially (basically triangles of it).

What I'm trying is make to a mesh with different zones of different colors on it.

I don't know if the problem is blending or what.

I've tried with `material.depthTest` and `material.depthWrite` without resolving it.
Sorry for my (very brief) explanation but is for a project and my client doesn't want me to reveal too much.

An example on threejs.org editor [here](http://es.tinypic.com/r/3492mvs/8)

Comment: Did you try to hide the planes when they are on the same position?

Comment: You can achieve better results by limiting the near and far clipping of your camera. This will of course limit your view distance in far and near but will achieve better accuracy for close objects like in your case i think. 
Also, i suggest you read up on three.js and depth sorting and stuff. 
As another point, you can fairly quickly create such meshes in Blender or any other Content Creation Software but maybe limiting the view range helps your case.
see here for further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695934/three-js-canvasrenderer-depth-sorting

Comment: If you place two planes very close, this problem is very hard to get rid of. I recommend you make a hole in the back plane so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Another option would be to use textures to color your plane.

Comment: What's the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using only planes, you could render to texture first and then use that texture on the largest plane. In the render to texture phase you could either have very close near and far values or disable depth checking.